# Error while creating a Java ME mobile application

Tags: java, netbeans, sdk

Im new to java ME and netbeans and Im trying to create a new mobile application, I have installed `Oracle ME 8.0 SDK` and activated it. I've added the platform but when I try to create a new Mobile application in the step 4 I have both `Emulator` plataform and `Device` in blank and I cant chose any other option.
Though I can still keep going with the project when I finish it I get a bunch of weird errors in my project, first one is :

```
-Fatal error: unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath

-Cannot find symbol, symbol: class MIDlet
```

Answer (score 0):

Without more details is hard to tell but it might be related to the use of classes not available on JavaME.

Check the documentation to see which classes are available and which are not [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/javame/javame-sdk/documentation/index.html).